# ASP.NET Core: IIS Express shows HTTP status 404 when it's actually a 500 - why?

Tags: asp.net, iis-express, asp.net-core-3.1

I have created a simple ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API REST service from the scaffolding template.

When an exception is thrown (in my case DI isn't able to create one of my data repository classes) IIS Express shows a HTTP `404 Page not Found` error instead of a `500 Server Error`.

Switching to Kestrel server, the original exception is displayed.

**Why doesn't IIS Express show the developer exception page?**

[image: IIS Express shows 404 instead of developer exception page]

---

#### Here is the Firefox developer tools network log when using IIS Express:

[image: Firefox developer tools network log]

---

#### Here is my code (excerpt):

```
public class WebConfiguration
{
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services
      .AddSwaggerGen()
      .AddControllers()
      ;
  }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, Options options)
  {
    Context.ConnectionString = options.DbConStr;

    if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    app
      .UseHttpsRedirection()
      .UseRouting()
      .UseAuthorization()
      .UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers())
      .UseSwagger()
      ;

    if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseSwaggerUI();
  }
}
```

```cs
[Route("/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUserAccess _repository;

    public UsersController(IUserAccess repository) => _repository = repository;

    [HttpGet]
    public ICollection<User> Get() => _repository.Get();

    [HttpGet("{familyName}")]
    public ICollection<User> Get(string familyName) => _repository.Get(familyName);
}
```

```
{
  "iisSettings":
  {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress":
    {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52772/swagger",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles":
  {
    "IIS Express":
    {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables":
      {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebAPI":
    {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables":
      {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the ports on the 2 screenshots you shared are different.

Comment: Sure they are: See `launchSettings.json`. One is served by IIS Express, the other one is served by Kestrel.

Comment: That's not a typical page from IIS modules (which should come with a unique style). So you'd better enable failed request tracing to learn more.

Comment: That's why it's a 404. The message is from Firefox. I added a network log from Firefox developer tools. --- Where would I enable trace logs in IIS Express? I couldn't find any information on how to enable it. Enabling the log file doesn't yield an entry in the logs (Only accessing the Swagger UI adds entries to the log).

Comment: Sorry, ignore my previous message, you're using IIS express. Are you able to access the Swagger endpoint?